# from Postman i'm able to get valid response body from an API, but from Application it throwing error for the same url

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

0.2
tomcat 9.0.53
the error is throw when i deploy the application to an external tomcat server.
if i run as an Springboot application (with same configuration) then there is no error.
also i can access the same api via postman.
`http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate`
`POST` method

```
    {"username":"User","password":"user"}

code:
URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            // Setting basic post request
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonData);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            Logger.info("nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String output;
            while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(output);
            }
            Logger.info(response.toString());
            in.close();


Error:

> 12-08-2021 @ 2:04:36PM : ERROR ---------->
> http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate
> [com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.post:63 <
> com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.parseAsObject:86] 
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate
>   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1909)
>   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
>   at com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.post(ApiHandler.java:55)  at
> com.edge.service.common.ApiHandler.parseAsObject(ApiHandler.java:86)
>   at
> com.edge.service.login.LoginService.authenticateuser(LoginService.java:44)
>   at
> com.edge.controller.login.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:66)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
```

Comment: please add relevant code in question

Comment: updated the description with the code

Comment: So where is this `http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate` file coming from, and is it really there? why isn't it `eplasapi/authenticate` as well?

Comment: infact both are same, api or epalsapi

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, there was an issue with the contextroot, cleaned and redoplyed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My Application started to work but i know that's an workaround.

when my API is deployed without an context root(http://localhost:9080/authenticate) its working. but with a context root(http://localhost:9080/**epals**api/authenticate), my UI application is throwing the above asked question.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:9080/api/authenticate
at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0